# How do I get a generic version of the binary search algorithm to find elements in list

Tags: java, binary-search

I've got something wrong with my search method.

```
public int search(T element)
   {
      int start = 0;
      int end = elements.length - 1;

      while (start <= end)
      {
         int middle = ((start + end) / 2);
         int result = element.compareTo(elements[middle]);
         if (result < 0)
         {
            start = middle - 1;
         }
         else if (result > 0)
         {
            end = middle + 1;
         }  
         else 
         {
            return middle;
         }   
      }
      return -1;
   }
```

My main method consists of an array, I need to call the search metho and have it print out where the element is ins the list.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String[] states = {"Tennessee", "North Carolina", "Kentucky", "Georgia", "Florida",
                         "Washington", "New York", "Vermont", "Oregon", "Wyoming"}; 

      GenericBinarySearchTree<String> sts = new GenericBinarySearchTree<String>(states);
      System.out.println("Vermont is the #" + sts.search("Vermont") + " element in the list!");
      System.out.println("Kentucky is the #" + sts.search("Kentucky") + " element in the list!");
   }
```

It can't find all the values. For instance, this is my output for Vermont and Kentucky:

```
Vermont is the #7 element in the list!
Kentucky is the #-1 element in the list!

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

I have tried all kinds of different things and looked at many examples but it still won't work properly.

Here is the class:

```
class GenericBinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> 
{
   private T[] elements;
   /*
   **Constructs an empty tree.
   */
   public GenericBinarySearchTree(T[] names)
   {  
      elements = names;
   }
   public int search(T element)
   {
      int start = 0;
      int end = elements.length - 1;

      while (start <= end)
      {
         int middle = ((start + end) / 2);
         int result = element.compareTo(elements[middle]);
         if (result < 0)
         {
            end = middle - 1;
         }
         else if (result > 0)
         {
            start = middle + 1;
         }  
         else 
         {
            return middle;
         }   
      }
      return -1;
   }
```

}

Comment: Your list needs to be sorted in order to use binary search

Comment: I am not familiar with `GenericBinarySearchTree`. Is this a class you have made (or has been provided to you)? If so, please post the code for it as well.

Comment: You don't actually have a tree, so don't call your class that. Also, "generic" is a poor name fragment. Just `BinarySearch` is best. Also, if `search` is your only method, just use a `static` method and pass in the array. You also need to sort your array first. Finally, there is no need for declaring a generic type, since you don't do anything with it - just use a wildcard